# Fire fox add on builder with existing add ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have already developed some add ons and submitted on mozilla . Now I want to use add on builder to work on my existing add ons . How can I do that ?

p.s. : this may not be the right place to ask such question. But I don;t know proper site to ask for. Experienced user may move this question to appropriate stackExchange site.

Comment: Is your add-on based on the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.10/)?

Comment: If it is based on the SDK, you *can* manually re-create all the files in your add-on in Builder. If your add-on is *NOT* based on the SDK, Builder will not help you as it is only meant to work with the Add-on SDK.

Answer (score 0):

All you can really do is copy and paste the add-on code to add-on builder.

Be warned though that Builder may be discontinued, after we have something better to offer which is where all of the work is going.